# Pandas update Dataframes while keep some columns as the old one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames and want to update the old one by the new one. However, I want to keep some specific columns as old values.

Here's a simple example:

```
data_old = {'name': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
            'datetime': ['2022-10-25 14:00', '2022-10-10 00:00', np.nan],
            'value': [1, 2, np.nan]}

data_new = {'name': ['name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name3'],
            'datetime': ['2022-10-25 14:00', '2022-10-10 00:00', '2022-10-10 01:00', '2022-10-10 22:00'],
            'value': [1, 3, 10, 8]}

df_old = pd.DataFrame(data=data_old)
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=data_new)
```

```
df_old
    name    datetime    value
0   name1   2022-10-25 14:35    1
1   name2   2022-10-10 00:00    2
2   name3   NaN NaN

df_new
name    datetime    value
0   name1   2022-10-25 14:00    1
1   name2   2022-10-10 00:00    3
2   name2   2022-10-10 01:00    10
3   name3   2022-10-10 22:00    8
```

I have tried `df_old.merge(df_new, how='right')`, it would overwrite the value of `value` column. Is it possible to keep the `value` column as the old one if it exists, while updating other columns?

The result should be like this (The `value` of the second row should be `2` instead of `3`):

```
name    datetime    value
0   name1   2022-10-25 14:00    1
1   name2   2022-10-10 00:00    2
2   name2   2022-10-10 01:00    10
3   name3   2022-10-10 22:00    8
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to produce the desired behaviour:

```
merged_df = df_old.merge(df_new, on='name', how='right')

filter1 = merged_df['datetime_y'].notnull()
filter2 = merged_df['value_x'].notnull()
filter3 = merged_df['datetime_x'] == merged_df['datetime_y']

merged_df['datetime'] = merged_df['datetime_y'].where(filter1, merged_df['datetime_x'])

merged_df['value'] = merged_df['value_x'].where(filter2 & filter3, merged_df['value_y']).astype('int')

merged_df = merged_df.drop(columns=['datetime_x', 'datetime_y', 'value_x', 'value_y'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out this method:

```
df_merge = df_old.merge(df_new, on=['name', 'datetime'], how='right')

df_merge['value'] = np.where(df_merge['value_x'].isna(),
                             df_merge['value_y'],
                             df_merge['value_x'])

df_merge = df_merge.drop(columns=['value_x', 'value_y'])
```